# What the purpose of OnModelCreating in EF4 Code-First?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, code-first

I was curious about what the purpose of OnModelCreating in EF4 Code-First context class? How does it work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a nice [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/12/06/ef-feature-ctp5-fluent-api-samples.aspx) in ADO.NET Team Blog.
In short, this event is mainly for Fluent mapping.

Comment: Link doesn't exist anymore

Answer (score 8):

OnModelCreating gives you access to a ModelBuilder instance that you can use to configure/customize the model.

As the previous answer mentions, you will typically use the code-first fluent API within it. Gil Fink has [posted](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/12/08/ef-feature-ctp5-code-first-fluent-api.aspx) what IMHO is a clearer explanation than the article cited in the previous answer.

For background info, Guthrie has a nice intro [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/08/announcing-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-release.aspx) on EF Code-First, and if you are wondering why its referred to as "fluent API", look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).