# EF 5 Code First with SQL Server Express 2012 and Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5, sql-server-express

I just cannot get this to work. I looked at all other related threads, and none of them work for me. Here is my connection string at the moment:

```
<add name='UniContext' connectionString='Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=ContosoUni;Integrated Security=SSPI;User Instance=true' providerName='System.Data.EntityClient'/>
```

The error I get is:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change provider name from System.Data.EntityClient to System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: Thank you Yusupov, that got rid of the error, but something isn't right, no tables are being created in my database on SQL Server Express ! Here is a screenshot ! [ http://goo.gl/znpYT ]

Comment: @Ciwan Do you have an initialization strategy? Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281447/ef-code-first-not-generating-tables , also you should map your classes on your database context with declaring DbSet or with using fluent interface in override of OnModelCreating method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759004/what-the-purpose-of-onmodelcreating-in-ef4-code-first

Comment: Thanks, I did the following: [ Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<UniContext>()); ] but still no tables are being created in my Database on SQL Express ! :(